# How to correctly use tabular/table

Tags: tables

What's wrong with this code, please?

```
\documentclass[franch]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Cs}
\centering
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Comparatif entre \textit{Two Track Unified Process} et \textit{Rational Unified Process}}
\begin{tabular}{|c{0.5cm}|c{0.5cm}|c{0.5cm}|c{0.5cm}|c{0.5cm}|}
\hline
& Axé développement & Projets cibles & Technologies & Architecture logicielle \\
\hline
RUP & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{images/danger} & >= 10 & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{images/danger} & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{images/danger} \\
\hline
2TUP & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{images/func_ok} & * & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{images/func_ok} & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{images/func_ok} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I couldn't be able to find the error. The table misses two vertical lines on output.

Comment: the `c` column does not, by default, accept a `width`. you'll need to consult [Center column with specifying width in table (tabular enviroment)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5017) and the links within

Comment: @cmhughes, when I replace that `c` by `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p` it still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a `\newcolumntype`:

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}             %% you need this
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       %% you need this
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    %% you need this
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Cs}
\centering
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Comparatif entre \textit{Two Track Unified Process} et \textit{Rational Unified Process}}
\begin{tabular}{|C{0.12\textwidth}*{4}{|C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}|}
\hline
& Axé développement & Projets cibles & Technologies & Architecture logicielle \\
\hline
RUP & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{example-image} & >= 10 & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{example-image-c} & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{example-image-a} \\
\hline
2TUP & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{example-image-a} & * & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{example-image-b} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @dgs Also you should take care of your french special characters `é`, `è` and also `>=` which are all not printed correctly

Comment: A minor nit to pick: add the instructions `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to enable the correct typesetting of accented characters such as `é`.