# How to fix tables without using the landscape instruction

Tags: tables, supertabular

I am looking for "experts on tables" :) I have different format of tables I have tried to fix them `\begin{landscape}` (it works, but I would prefer if my tables all looked the same). I have tried to use `\scriptsize`... it makes some of my tables "a bit ugly" very small.

Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6RXQUqktUOX1hURFczQTVNZ2c/view?usp=sharing) to my project. Since I have to use this template, I could not write the whole code here as it is too long. I would like that you see the default parameters on this template, maybe I have to change some package or you would suggest me to add something (so that to make it easy I provide you the whole work). I have included some tables which are okay! and added comment to say that they are okay, I will be grateful for all who could help me fix them. I have tried a lot but did not succeed.

Before asking the help of expert people I tried things like "[How to fix the column width of my table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369190/how-to-fix-the-column-width-of-my-table)", by visiting similar questions but it does not work for me on this template, however the same code they shared works fine not on this template that I am obliged to use. That is why I am looking for experts who could help.

Comment: How many columns do you have in your table? Do all of them just contain text? Are you familiar with the `p` column type that lets you wrap text inside table cells, or are you restricting yourself to `lcr` column types only?

Comment: @MichaelPalmer hi Michael thank you for feedback basically they are different ( there is tables with 22 columns other less... ) both text and number.. no unfortunately not very familiar with :( that is way am asking for help  what do you suggest exactly please (maybee I did not understand!)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: You are likely to get more effective help if you post a minimal working example here illustrating the problem. First, your question should help future users, even if the content of external links changes. Second, few people are likely to be willing to trawl through your entire project in order to see if they can help you. Be realistic: you want to make it easy for people to see if they might be able to help by glancing at your question.

Comment: @cfr  but in this case you could not maybee be able to help me if you could not take a look on the template beacause honestly am not very familar with latex so I could not ust provide you my tables code I don't know if it will works ( or what I have to fix exactly so that it would be okey I have tried the code https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369190/how-to-fix-the-column-width-of-my-table in order to be able to use `\begin{tabular}{cC{3cm}c}` for example, it works  seperatly but not on this template even I have added the packages used that s way I provide the prject

Comment: Please ***read the instructions @HenriMenke linked***. Producing a minimal example is just a mechanical process. You don't need any special knowledge of LaTeX.

Comment: it is okey thank you any way for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]When I run your tex file tables are cliped to the right side, I used the package name `\usepackage{changepage}` to shift the table environment by using the environment `adjustwidth` no need to write `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}` again and again in tex file but to declare it globaly so i used in the preamble to get the effect.

```
 \begin{table}
  %\centering 
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{}
  \begin{tabular}{cC{5cm}cc}
  \hline Summary   & Feature ordering & Test CR (\%) & Training time (second) \\
  \hline  Normal LSSVM & --- & 86.63      & 4.794\\
  \hline ILSSVM-Orig  & (1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18)-(19-20-21-22) & 90.91 & 0.508 \\      
  \hline  OILSSVM-Desc &(2-13-5-9-22-20-15-11-21-6-8-18-10-7-19-14-17-16)-(3-12-4-1) & \textbf{97.73} & \textbf{0.505 } \\
  \hline  OILSSVM-Asce & (1-4-12-3-17-14-19-7-10-18-8-6-21-11-15-20-22)-(9-5-13-2) &  86.36 & 0.716 \\
  \hline OILSSVM-Rand  & (1-11-12-2-5-6-7-8-3-4-9-10-13-15-18-14-17-20-(19-22-21-16) & 84.09 & 0.814  \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{ tableau 2}
  \label{table:2}
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \end{table}
```

Comment: I am definetly gratefull for you Biki, because you have tried :)  thank you! It works well :) "je vous remercie merci merci :)" I was stuck for a long time, but you, you have really make the effort to help thank you all the best :) ( I could not upvote your answer I have not the suffisiant previliges but I make it as a usefull answer so that all people could make use thank you :) (y) :)

Comment: @Biki Teron, sorry, but I don't understand what connection has environment `adjustwidth` with new column type `C{...}`? Probably your answer be more clear for others (not only OP), if you will show preamble to your solution (well, also OP should made a MWE ...).

Comment: @https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/56260/biki-teron Dear Biki it is me again as I said previously your solution works (zero error) on a template I have worked on, just  today I have to work on another tempate given by the university (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6RXQUqktUONWdWUTFodDUwS2c/view?usp=sharing) I faced a little problm and since you were the only one who could help me to fix my tables I return back asking your help I have added the package `\usepackage{changepage}` it gives me athe problm that it does not support the fact that there is`cC{3cm}c` for example and thankyou again

Comment: @Biki I have commented like this `(@Biki Teron  ...(packages I add)... @Biki Teron)` the packages I added  on reportECD.cls , so that you could help me find how to fix the problm on this template I will be definetely gratefull for your support I tried by myself since it works on other temptate but since am not very familiar with I did not succeed :) thank you for your time and consideration :) you could see also the pdf generated the table is showed but a little on the left and the error : ! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.
....cC{3cm}c.

Comment: Dear @Biki it works!  by adding this  in repoertECD.cls even if I use `\centering` it is all the time on the left any suggestion!
`\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1} %interligne
\setlength{\parskip}{0.3cm}`