# centering a threepart table in article document classes

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, elsarticle, threeparttable

I have a threeparttable in which its cells are needed to be centered. I have tested all `\centering` and `\begin{center}…\end{center}` commands. But these commands do not work! Although there is no error, the texts in the cells are still left aligned. This is my table:

```
\documentclass{elsart5p}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{threeparttable}
%\centering
\begin{center}
\caption{myTable}\label{tab:table1}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}

\begin{tabular}[width=\linewidth]{p{0.6\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}}
\toprule
Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header1&Header Header Header Header Header2\\
     \midrule 
col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1* & col2 col2 col2 \\
cell3 cell3& cell4 cell4 cell4 cell4 cell4\\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item *Star: important
\end{tablenotes}

\end{center}
\end{threeparttable}


\end{document}
```

The texts to be written in some cells are too long, so I had to use  `\begin{tabular}[width=\linewidth]{p{0.6\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}}` command to break the text of each cell into two or three lines.

How can I centerize this table?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The `\begin{center}...\end{center}` environment will centre the whole table, but not the cells whose alignment is specified in the options for `\begin{tabular}`. Specifically, you currently have two columns which are justified, given by `p{0.6\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}`. This answer will show you how to make these centered: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/center-column-with-specifying-width-in-table-tabular-enviroment/5020#5020

Comment: @rbrignall: Thank you for your welcome and your help. I tested the answer you guided, but it doesn't allow long cells to be broken automatically. The table gets larger than  linewidth.

Comment: @user206714 - The reason the overall width of the `tabular` environment exceeds `\linewidth` is that the total width of a cell is the sum of its usable width and the left-hand and right-hand padding (in the amount of `\tabcolsep` each). Hence, the width of your `tabular` environment is actually `\linewidth+4\tabcolsep` rather than just `\linewidth`. In the answer I just posted, I suggest you switch to a `tabularx` environment and specify (a) the intended overall width (here: `\linewidth`) and (b) the *relative* column widths (here: 3 to 2, or 1.2 to 0.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments and observations:

- The `tabular` environment does *not* take an intended-width argument. The only arguments recognized by `tabular` affect the vertical positioning relative to neighboring elements: `t`, `c` (the default), and `b`. `width=\linewidth` is simply ignored.
- You're probably thinking of the `tabularx` environment. By default, its `X` column type typesets the material fully-justified. To get a centered version of the `X` column type, define it via

  ```
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  ```
- If you want to make the first column 50% wider than the second, you should write

  ```
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}C >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}C @{}}
  ```

  Observe that `1.2=1.5*0.8` and also `1.2+0.8=2` -- the number of columns of type `X`.
- The `threeparttable` environment should be embedded in a `table` environment. Use `\tnote` directives to place free-format footnote markers, and use `\item` statements within the `tablenotes` environment to start off the associated footnote text.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsart5p}
\usepackage{caption,tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
%% \setlength\tabcolsep{6pt} % that's the default!
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{myTable}
\label{tab:table1}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}C >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}C @{}}
\toprule
Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header1&
Header Header Header Header Header2\\
\midrule
col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1 col1\tnote{*} &
col2 col2 col2 \\
cell3 cell3& 
cell4 cell4 cell4 cell4 cell4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\medskip
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[*]Star: important
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine