# Center second column in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to center all my columns in my table but I only get the first column to be centered, can anyone help me out?

This is the code i am using:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{The four main criteria for conceptual model evaluation.}
\label{concept_criteria}
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{12cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Criteria} &  \textbf{Description}\\ 
    \hline
    Validity  &  A modelers perception that the conceptual model can  be converted into an computer model accurate enough for the purpose at hand \\
    \hline
    Credability  &  The clients perception that the conceptual model can be converted into a computer model accurate enough for the purpose at hand  \\
    \hline
    Utility  & The conceptual model can be developed into a computer model that can be used as decision making in the specific context \\
    \hline
    Feasibility  & The conceptual model can be converted into a computer model with the time, resources and data available \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{12cm}` horizontally centers the contents of the second column.

Comment: See also: [Center column with specifying width in table (tabular enviroment)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5017/134144)  and [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/134144)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, para mode `p{00cm)` alignment doesn't have `center` alignment by default, you need to define as:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}%
\begin{tabular}{P{10cm}
```

Else should follow `leandriis` comment...