# Multicolumn width uneven

Tags: tables, multicolumn, width

I am trying to create a table with this code;

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Mean Partnership Duration & \multicolumn  {4}{c|}{\centering Number of simulations resulting in an epidemic}\\

\cline{2-5}
No. & head 1 & head 2& head 3 & head 4\\
\hline
1 & data1 & data2 & data 3 & data4\\
\hline
2 & data1 & data2 & data 3 & 4\\
\hline
3 & data1 & data2 & data 3& 4\\
\hline
4 & data1 & data2 & data 3& 4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is the ideal table}
\label{My table}
\end{table}
```

But the 4th subcolumn labelled 'head 4' is larger than the other subcolumns. I want all 4 columns to be equal in width,
Any advice?
All the best,

Comment: Welcome. Does this (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/center-column-with-specifying-width-in-table-tabular-enviroment) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle apologies I meant Multicolumn

Comment: Hi! Now you have three answers :-). You may consider to up-vote each of them you liked ( by clicking on up-triangle at top left side of answers) and accept one of the, which solve your problem on the best way  ( by clicking on check mark at top left side of selected answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use of the `makecell` and `tabularx` packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{5}{C|} }
    \hline
\makecell{Mean\\ Partnership\\ Duration}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Number of simulations resulting in an epidemic}\\
\cline{2-5}
No. & head 1 & head 2 & head 3 & head 4\\
\hline
1   & data 1 & data 2 & data 3 & data4\\
\hline
2   & data 1 & data 2 & data 3 & 4\\
\hline
3   & data 1 & data 2 & data 3 & 4\\
\hline
4   & data 1 & data 2 & data 3 & 4\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{This is the ideal table}
\label{My table}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is excellent thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Define a new column type (package `array`) using an `m` column of the desired width. (`m` will center vertically the `multicolumn` cell).

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering \arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}}
```

Using the same package it is possible expand the cells vertically

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<a number>}
```

[image: x]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe} % show margins

\usepackage{calc}%<<<<<<<<<<<<< added
\usepackage{array} %<<<<<<<<<<<<< added
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering \arraybackslash}m{(\textwidth-(6\arrayrulewidth)-(10\tabcolsep))/5}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< optional
    
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|C|C|C|C|C|}
            \hline
            Mean Partnership Duration & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Number of simulations resulting in an epidemic}\\           
            \cline{2-5}
            No. & head 1 & head 2& head 3 & head 4\\
            \hline
            1 & data1 & data2 & data 3 & data4\\
            \hline
            2 & data1 & data2 & data 3 & 4\\
            \hline
            3 & data1 & data2 & data 3& 4\\
            \hline
            4 & data1 & data2 & data 3& 4\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{This is the ideal table}
        \label{My table}
    \end{table} 
    
\end{document
```

Comment: Your tabular is too wide. You should replace `0.2\textwidth` by `(\textwidth-(6\arrayrulewidth)-(10\tabcolsep))/5`.

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (you need several compilations).

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{nicematrix}

 \begin{document}

 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
     
 \begin{table}[ht]
 \centering
 \begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[hvlines,columns-width=auto]
 \Block{2-1}{}
 \Block{}{Mean\\ Partnership\\ Duration} & \Block{1-4}{Number of simulations resulting in an epidemic}\\ 
 No. & head 1 & head 2& head 3 & head 4\\
 1 & data1 & data2 & data 3 & data4\\
 2 & data1 & data2 & data 3 & 4\\
 3 & data1 & data2 & data 3& 4\\
 4 & data1 & data2 & data 3& 4\\
 \end{NiceTabular}
 \caption{This is the ideal table}
 \label{My table}
 \end{table} 
     
 \end{document}
```

The key `hvlines` draws all the rules, excepted in the blocks created by `Block` (that's why I have added an empty block `\Block{2-1}{}` to avoid a rule under the left-uppermost cell.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks for the help!